# Google Shared Drive sync to my PC

Tags: sync, google-drive

I have the Google Backup & Sync installed and it syncs my personal Drive to my PC with no problem here. But I also have access to some Shared Drives which I also want to sync my PC so I can work out of files from software that isn't supported on Google Drive which doesn't seem to be possible.

Do any of you power users know how to do this? How to add a 2nd drive to my Backup & Sync. Maybe some other software?

Comment: Are you certain the files themselves aren't causing the issue?  For example, some files like .ost or .pst for Outlook will not work in that manner, regardless of which hosting service is in use.

Comment: @Arctiic no I am talking about the software not giving me the possibility to even choose to sync this shared drive. It is only showing "My Drive" in the options. I am logged in with the same google account.

Comment: @Finiox I have the same problem. Do you mind if I edit your question to make it a bit more clear and maybe increase chances for a solution?

Comment: @Benjamin not at all

Comment: @Benjamin added an edit, hope it helps?

Answer (score 16):

Apparently you cannot add shared folders as actual folders to "my drive" anymore by some web UI element. It's only possible to create shortcuts (.gshortcut) for now. Unfortunately, these shortcuts do not allow the folders to be synced by "backup and sync".

However, there's a somewhat hidden key combo that establishes the "old" way. When you select the shared folder in "shared with me", you can press "Shift-Z" (btw, this is listed in key combos available from the gear icon top right), and then select where to put the shared folder inside "my drive". "backup and sync" will now pickup this as a real folder.

Comment: Awesome!!! It works for me. This "Add to My Drive" option can't see in Menu but your "Shift-Z" shortcut works! Thanks.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you @JeffRSon!

Comment: I guess they removed this; Giving server error to me. Can you recheck ?

Comment: I currently don't have another share to try, but Shift-Z is still listed in the shortcut keys list. I would expect it to work. Maybe try again?

Comment: Shift+Z FTW!!!!

Comment: as of May 2022 this solution partially doesn't work any longer - the shared folders (added under "My Drive") are downloaded as shortcuts (files with .lnk extension on Windows), and you can "browse" them "offline" only while Google Drive app is running.

Comment: yes, it's a bad move by google

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I misunderstood at first, but if I'm comprehending your question correctly, all you need to do is right-click or access the context menu of the file or directory that was shared to you from browser, and select "Add to My Drive".  The file will be added to a folder that also shows up in your explorer.exe, and it *should* still sync (not a redundant copy), assuming Backup & Sync is running.

EDIT: After seeing some more comments, I went digging through the Google Drive Help community and managed to find [this post](https://support.google.com/drive/thread/9622524?hl=en), I hope this might provide more details or answers for those with the questions about this particular problem.  Here's a screen capture for retention:

[image: Screen capture]

Comment: I right clicked the shared drive from the left menu. These are the only options I got. http://prntscr.com/q004uv 
If we are talking about shared folders then yes I can add it to backup and sync. But not a shared *drive*. Are there permissions the drive admin needs to set?

Comment: I don't see any "Add to My Drive" option. Only "Add shortcut to Drive". My shortcut folders do not sync.

Comment: @MattFitzmaurice Added an edit, hope it helps!